# prove that any ordered field has the rational as subfield

Tags: real-analysis

The claim is that rational embeds in any ordered field. I think embeds means an injective homomorphism.

Here is attempt idea to prove it:

Associate 1 in the rational with 1 in the field and from that get any integer $n$ gets associated with $1+1+...+1$ n times in the field. So this way we get a copy of $Z$ in the ordered field. from the subfield, we rationalize it and show that rationalized one is inside the field.

Is this on  the right track?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the fact of order to show that you get a copy of $\mathbb Z$ and not the finite field $\mathbb Z_p$

Answer (score 0):

I think so.  Since we're in a field,  $n$ has an inverse.  So we have $1/n$.  Then by adding,  $k/n$.